# Drag & Drop in table using jQuery (using two draggable,droppable functions)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery for my drag & drop requirement, idk the reason why not working here is my below code
my requirement is like first when I drag the images into the table cell then I'm enabling/showing a div later I am dragging a span to the newly showing div which was enabled when the image is dragged then the span is not droppable inside that enabled div idk why need help I'm new to jQuery.

```js
 compose='';
 compose +='<div id="data-hide" class="db-click">'; 
  compose +='<p class="margin5 strong drop-able ">'; 
    compose +='<img src="xyz.png" /></p>'; 
     compose +='<p class="margin5 strong drop-able">';
   compose +='<img src="abc.png" /></p></div>'; 


$("#init").draggable( {
       opacity: 0.5,
        helper: "clone",
      } ); 

     $("td").droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
         drop: function(event, ui) {
            $("#slot").html(compose);
        }, 
        
    }); 

     $(".drag-able").draggable({
        opacity: 0.5,
        helper :"clone",
     }); 
     
      $(".drop-able").droppable({
        drop : function(event,ui){
            $(this).append(ui.draggable.clone());
        } 
     });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div><img src="xyz.png" id="init"/></div>

<div class="textdata">
<span class="drag-able">hello</span>
</div>

<table>
<tr>
<td id="slot"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

so there the problem is after dragging the image the composed div block is enabled/attached inside the table cell after that when we drag the span onto the div inside the table cell is not dropping the span text.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your `<p class="margin5 strong drop-able ">` with not work with `$(".drop-able").droppable({` since the new p was not a part of the dom when the `$(".drop-able").droppable({` code ran

Comment: so what i have to .? instead of p do i have to use span/div.?

Comment: No it has nothing to do with the element type, you have to bind `.droppable()` to the newly created element

Comment: $("td").droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) {
   $("#slot").html(compose);
   //$("p").droppable();
   //$(".drop-able").droppable();
    $("#data-hide").droppable(); 
   }, 
 });
i have made those changes but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var compose = $("<div>", {
    id: "data-hide",
    class: "db-click"
  });
  $("<p>", {
    class: "margin5 strong drop-able"
  }).appendTo(compose);
  $("<img>", {
    src: "xyz.png"
  }).appendTo($("p", compose));
  $("<p>", {
    class: "margin5 strong drop-able"
  }).appendTo(compose);
  $("<img>", {
    src: "abc.png"
  }).appendTo($("p:eq(1)", compose));


  $("#init").draggable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    helper: "clone",
  });

  $(".drag-able").draggable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    helper: "clone",
  });

  $("td").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $("#slot").html(compose);
      $("#slot .drop-able").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).append(ui.draggable.clone());
        }
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#slot {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div><img src="xyz.png" id="init" /></div>
<div class="textdata">
  <span class="drag-able">hello</span>
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="slot"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As was mentioned in the comments, the when the HTML Elements are dropped into the table, they had not previously existed in the DOM. This means the initial droppable was never initialized upon them.

To correct this, the initialization of the droppable needs to be done after they exist in the DOM.

Comment: yeah, it is working but that composing syntax is a bit new to me, i want to add text inside <p> tag how can i do it i tried by adding text attribute but not working.
anyway Thank u @Twisty.

Comment: @UttamKonduru you can use `.text()` but `.html()` might be better. `$("<p>", { class: "margin5 strong drop-able" }).html("Some Text").appendTo(compose);`

Comment: okay.. but what exactly this means-> appendTo($("p:eq(1)", compose)); i.e p:eq(1) , why i'm aksing cuz when i add new <p> beween them then again the droppable not working.

Comment: @UttamKonduru it is a selector for the second `p` element found inside `compose`.